# How do I remove row with duplicate value in kdb?

Tags: kdb

I have a table of data in kdb and I would like to use q to remove the rows which contain a duplicate value in one column.

For example, if I have the following table where there is a duplicate value in the `Age` column:

```
Name    Age    Degree
---------------------
Alice   26     Science
Bob     34     Arts
Carrie  26     Engineering
```

How would I delete the third row so I end up with the following:

```
Name    Age    Degree
---------------------
Alice   26     Science
Bob     34     Arts
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You could do

```
select from t where i=(first;i)fby Age
```

Answer (score 3):

You can delete any of the duplicates in any columns using this:

```
q)delete from t where ({not x in 1#x};i) fby Age
Name  Age Degree
-----------------
Alice 26  Science
Bob   34  Arts
```

Could also be solved using a by clause instead of fby, but in this case to get the first occurrence of each age you have to use reverse

```
q)0!select by Age from reverse t
Age Name  Degree
-----------------
26  Alice Science
34  Bob   Arts
```